# Correct http status code to use if delete was only partially successful?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I have a `REST` `API` that allows users to delete documents in a nosql database. Any child documents will also be removed. ..

```
DELETE /api/document/dummyId
```

So this would delete document with `id` of `dummyId` and any child documents.

If successful, respond with a status code of `204`.

If 2 out of 3 child documents fail to delete, for whatever reason, I'd like to include these in the `body` of response back to client.

What status code is most appropriate here? Considering some documents where deleted and others were not.

Comment: Shouldn't the operation be transactional?

Comment: No, I'm using CouchDB which uses an "optimistic concurrency" model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no correct HTTP status code for this, because the `DELETE` statement *MUST* either fully succeed or not do anything at all.

There's not really a "partial success" in HTTP. WebDAV does add this to some features, but even in WebDAV the `DELETE` must fully succeed or not affect the state of the resource.